# Post request to a service, get response ,validate response

Tags: c#, web-services, unit-testing, soap, automation

I am looking for a sample code to send request to a web service( SOAP) using C# .net
Get the response back and then validate the response automatically

Ex:http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit
 Send celcius data to this web service and get some response back and then validate this response with expected values.

I am looking to do this programmatically using C# nunit framework
Does anyone have idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to write a unit test for the CelsiusToFahrenheit web service?

Comment: is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529578.aspx) anything useful?

Comment: I used the above service for reference, this is what I am trying to achieve send some input to a web service, get the response and assert that response

Comment: may be I did not explain this correctly, lets say there is a method  which accepts Celcius as value and returns Fahreheit values  I want to check the correctness of the fahrenheit values with some predefined values

Comment: You should refactor the code that does the actual conversion and unit-test that (see my answer below). asmx web-services (i'm assuming that's what it is since you mention SOAP) are hard to test, which is a problem. All you can do is test the actual logic by refactoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;  
using System.IO;  
using System.Net;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Xml;  
using NUnit.Framework;  


namespace Examples.System.Net  
{  
    public class WebRequestPostExample  
    {  
        public static void Main()  
        {  
String b = "OK";  
            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 


        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("your end point here");  


        request.Headers.Add ("SOAPAction", "some soap action here");  
        request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";  
        request.Accept = "text/xml";  
        request.Method = "POST";


        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.  
        request.Method = "POST";  
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.  
        string postData = @"<s:Envelope xmlns:s="Som request that you want to send";  

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);  
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;  
        Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();  


        stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);  

        int a = 0;  
        stream.Close();  
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();  
        Assert.AreEqual(response.StatusCode, b, "Pass");  


        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
```

Answer (score 0):

**There should be no logic worth testing in the web service itself.**

You cannot easily test the web service call, and nor should you. This is the responsibility of the Framework.

Your web service should be a wrapper around the class that does the real work. You would then unit test the class with the logic in, not the web service.

In your example, you should have a class who's responsibility it is to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius. The public method that does this would be covered by your unit tests.

The end point you call to actually perform the conversion (for example, the methods in your .asmx file) would simply call the code above.